# C returning structs via pointer

Tags: c, pointers, allegro5

I am currently starting to work with c and allegro5. I want to put my initialization code into an init() method, but I am struggling to return the pointers to the ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE and the ALLEGRO_DISPLAY. Although the pointers are initialized in the function, they are still NULL afterwards; I thought that values assigned to pointers would survive the end of the current scope, because the underlying value is modified, but the memory address stays the same. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

void init(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display_ptr, ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *queue_ptr) {
    al_init();
    al_install_keyboard();
    display_ptr =  al_create_display(640, 480);
    queue_ptr = al_create_event_queue();
    al_register_event_source(queue_ptr, al_get_display_event_source(display_ptr));

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

    al_flip_display();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

   ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
   ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;

   init(display, event_queue);
   printf("%d\n", display == NULL); //prints out 1
   printf("%d\n", event_queue == NULL); //prints out 1

   //Further code

   return 0;
}
```

Any hint or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the pointer itself.

Try it like this

```
void init(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY **display_ptr, ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE **queue_ptr) {
    al_init();
    al_install_keyboard();
    *display_ptr =  al_create_display(640, 480);
    *queue_ptr = al_create_event_queue();
    /* I assume you are guaranteed to not recieve `NULL's or why don't you check ? */
    al_register_event_source(*queue_ptr, al_get_display_event_source(*display_ptr));

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

    al_flip_display();
}
```

and

```
init(&display, &event_queue);
```

Remember that in c you always pass by value, so the passed pointers are copied, while they contain the same address they are stored in different places, hence altering one of them, doesn't affect the other.

Passing the address to the pointer, you can modify the address stored in the pointer.

If you want to check that what I say is true, try printing the address of the pointers in each function and you will see that they are different.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are called by value, i.e. in your case the pointer address is not returned.

To work around that you need to pass pointers to pointers like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

void init(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY **display_ptr, ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE **queue_ptr) {
    al_init();
    al_install_keyboard();
    *display_ptr =  al_create_display(640, 480);
    *queue_ptr = al_create_event_queue();
    al_register_event_source(*queue_ptr, al_get_display_event_source(*display_ptr));

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

    al_flip_display();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

   ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
   ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;

   init(&display, &event_queue);
   printf("%d\n", display == NULL); //prints out 1
   printf("%d\n", event_queue == NULL); //prints out 1

   //Further code

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is debatable. It is a workaround for not having call by reference like e.g. C++.

Comment: You mean that c is inferior because it doesn't make your life harder by having pass by reference? In my opinion pass by reference is confusing, because you can forget that the passed variable will be modified, so having pass by reference is one of the ugly things in c++, and it once costed me a lot of money.